# have PyRun_InteractiveLoop() take input/output from/to another pty on linux

Tags: python, linux, pty

In a C program I want to run a Python interactive loop that takes its input from and makes its output to a pseudo terminal (for example pts/4) different than the one from which the C program was launched (for example pts/1).

The basic way to run an interactive loop is:

```
PyRun_InteractiveLoop(stdin, "<stdin>");
```

This however does not solve the problem because it uses the pseudo terminal from which the program was launched (pts/1), and not pts/4.

A solution that works is:

```
int fd = open("/dev/pts/4", O_RDWR);
dup2(fd, 0);
dup2(fd, 1);
dup2(fd, 2);
PyRun_InteractiveLoop(stdin, "<stdin>");
```

The drawback of this solution is that it makes file descriptors 0 1 2 unavailable for communicating with the pseudo terminal from which the program was launched. And while these descriptors could have been dup'ed before-hand, there are some functions that insist on using 0 1 2 and that cannot use dup'ed fds.

Ideally we would like the interactive loop to not rely on fds 0 1 2, and to be run on /dev/pts/4 like this:

```
FILE *pts = fopen("/dev/pts/4", "rw");
PyRun_InteractiveLoop(pts, "/dev/pts/4");
```

Unfortunately this does not work as expected and has the same effect as using stdin, which by default uses the pseudo-terminal from which the program was launched.

So the question is twofold:

- If PyRun_InteractiveLoop() can only run on stdin / fds 0 1 2, why does it take any arguments at all?
- If it actually can work on something else than stdin / fds 0 1 2, and in particular on a user-defined pseudo-terminal, how should it be called to do that?

Comment: As often, after days of searching, it's just few minutes after asking for help that I find the answer on my own: http://bugs.python.org/issue14916